# Toast Notifications group

Tags: c#, notifications, uwp

In UWP I am using Toast Notifications. Like this:

```
ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());
var notification = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
notification.Show(toast);
```

And everything is working just fine, but when I do this multiple times, the notifications are showing one by one, when I remove the current one the next one shows. I want to show each new notification above previous, like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I think this was possible on Win 8/8.1.. in Win 10 the notifications are queued (and shown one after the other) so that the notifications don't clutter the UI ..

Answer (score 3):

That is the only achievable behavior in Windows 10. I think the reason is that the notifications are now actionable compared to Windows 8, so they appear one by one so that the user is able to respond to them. The notifications appear all together at once in action center only.

Comment: @user3230349 If this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.